# 99 Buick Century died while driving down highway. When stopped, smoke was coming from engine

Tags: oil, overheating, oil-leak, buick, century

my car died while driving down the highway after I got to the side of highway smoke was coming from engine was white pop up hood. an I seen next to my oil cap a rubber black hose with a rubber elbow was blown I don't know what the hose is called  but I checked oil an it was low did my car blow up??or is there some kind of safety shut off  when it gets to the point of high temps??? please let me know if you can help

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The part you're describing as a black rubber hose sounds like a radiator hose. The white smoke would have been hot coolant. If the car quit due to losing coolant, more than likely the engine has severely overheated. This will most likely incur major engine work or possibly even replacement.